# Gleamtech DocumentUltimate Cache file Path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the **Gleamtech's DocumentUltimate** Document Viewer in C# and want to get the cache folder name. which is created when a document is loaded.

Example : ~ App_Data\DocumentCache\~krcth

```
var cache = DocumentUltimateWebConfiguration.Current.GetCache();
string folder=cache.LocationId;
```

But it returns the same value every time and there is no folder for the same value. Is there any way I can get the newly created cache folder name?

Whole Code is down Below, I am trying to delete cache of a user when it exceeds 2 as multiple caches are slowing down the response.

```
DataTable docache = new DataTable();
if(Session["docache"] == null)
{   
    docache.Columns.Add("Path");
    docache.Columns.Add("Time");
    docache.Columns.Add("Number");
}
else
{
    docache = (DataTable)Session["docache"];
}

var cache = DocumentUltimateWebConfiguration.Current.GetCache();
string path =cache.LocationId;
int cachecount = Convert.ToInt32(hfcache.Value.ToString());

cachecount++;

docache.Rows.Add(path, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss"), cachecount);
hfcache.Value = Convert.ToString(cachecount);

if(docache.Rows.Count >2)
{
    string deletecachepath=Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DocumentCache/" +                         docache.Rows[0]["Path"].ToString());
    DeleteDirectory(deletecachepath);
    docache.Rows[0].Delete();
}

Session["docache"] = docache;
//End
```

Anyone Have any idea about this?

Comment: Why not try [their support](https://support.gleamtech.com/Main/)? They probably know more that someone on SO.

Comment: i have tried their support you can see a number of questions that i have asked, they didn't gave me any support. That's why i have asked this question on stackoverflow.